# Loading a game center match with custom view controller

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode

I have made a game center turn-based game and I've been using apple standard game overview screen. It works good but now I am also using a custom viewcontroller so I can get the game center one out of my app. I've used the ray wenderlich one in his paid iOS 5 book.

My game updates the game string everytime with 12 letters however it doesn't goes correctly in the custom view controller, the custom viewcontroller always misses the last 12 letters but when I open the game in the apple view controller the correct string loads. So it's not because of the way I send the string.

To load matches I use a button:

```
-(void)loadAMatch:(GKTurnBasedMatch *)match {
[vc dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion:nil];
[[GCTurnBasedMatchHelper sharedInstance] turnBasedMatchmakerViewController:nil didFindMatch:match];
}
```

Is there anyone who knows why I have this problem please if more code is needed to clear something tell me.